# Reading 2 numbers in assembly and storing it in a variable

Tags: variables, assembly

just to put it out there -I really did search and try to find an easy to understand tutorial but couldn't :/ .. I'm still kind of new to it.

But what I'm struggling with is to input 2 numbers from the user and to store it in a variable . And then later compare it to a Maximum value.

```
output db 10,13, "Enter a number: $"
asq dw 10,13, "$" ; ascii values for a new line
stilltoimplement db 10,13, "Do calculations $"

.code 

jmp start 

    number db ?
    max db 14

start:
    mov ax,@data 
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,09 ;prints new line
    mov dx, offset output
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01 ;checks for key
    mov al, 01
    int 21h
    mov number, al


    cmp number,14
    jg start
    jl part2

part2:

    mov ah,09
    mov dx,offset stilltoimplement
    int 21h

ending:
    mov ah,4ch
    mov al,00
    int 21h ;End the program

END
```

Comment: `int 21h/ah=01h` just reads a single character (ie. you will get the ascii code for a single digit). Are you fine with reading a single digit, is it supposed to be a byte (as it is now) or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add multiple-digit numbers, you could store the digits
 in a register by multiplying the current number by 10 on a digit
 input.

I would guess that you are on x86 so you have 6 general purpose
 registers.

In assembler-like pseudocode:

```
 register a = 0 
 register b = 0 
 register c = 0 

 num1:

 c = getDigit() 
 if c is a delimiter/sentinel value jump to num2
 a = a * 10 
 a = a + c 
 jump to num1

 num2: 

 c = getDigit() 
 if c is a delimiter/sentinel value jump to sum
 b = b * 10 
 b = b + c 
 jump to num2

 sum:
 a = a + b
```

and your sum is now in a